# ActionBar-PullToRefresh: can not scroll down

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, actionbarsherlock, pull-to-refresh

Im using chrisbanes ActionBar-PullToRefresh in a GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarsherlock.PullToRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/ptr_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/GV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:columnWidth="75dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="6dp" />
</uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarsherlock.PullToRefreshLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="SomeTxt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="SomeTxt2"

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Bt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SomeTxt3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Bt2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SomeTxt4" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The GridView contains lots of items and Views from `LinearLayout2`dosent show on the Screen.

Its also not possible for the users to scroll down. 
is there any way to solve the scroll down?

Answer (score 0):

use RelativeLayout as root container